# Python equivalent of lua bit32.bxor

Tags: python, lua, equivalent

I am trying to "convert" a lua script into a python script, but the lua script seems to have a library named bit32, and of which it uses the bxor function. Is there any python equivalent of the bit32.bxor function?

I have searched multiple times on stackoverflow and google for what the equivalent is, but i didn't find any. Maybe I'm just searching the wrong stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the script trying to calculate Exclusive OR of 2 integers ? if so you can use the bitwise operator `^`

```py
>>>8 ^ 16
24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ^ operator to perform bitwise exclusive XOR.

```
result = 10 ^ 20 ^ 30 ^ 40
print(result)  # Output: 40
```

Comment: Should it be `40` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Python provides bitwise XOR using the bitwise operator `^`. However, you can use a function if you want, using the [`operator.xor(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) function.

You can also use [NumPy's bitwise XOR function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html) as an equivalent.